# jQuery: if class=active?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('a#fav').bind('click', function() {
        addFav(<?php echo $showUP["uID"]; ?>);
    });
});
```

I need to modify this so if the a#fav has class="active" then it should do

```
  removeFav(<?php echo $showUP["uID"]; ?>);
```

instead
How can i do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You want to use the `hasClass` function

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('a#fav').bind('click', function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            removeFav(<?php echo $showUP["uID"]; ?>);
        }
        else {
            addFav(<?php echo $showUP["uID"]; ?>);
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT**: And just for fun, another way to write it in a more condensed format

```
$(function() {    
    $('a#fav').bind('click', function() {
        var uID = <?php echo $showUP["uID"]; ?>;
        ($(this).hasClass('active') ? removeFav : addFav)(uID);
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 I like your last version. Just noticed you had it, so I deleted mine. Although you could make it single line if you get rid of the `uID` variable. :o)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('a#fav').bind('click', function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active'))
            removeFav(<?php echo $showUP["uID"]; ?>);
        else
             addFav(<?php echo $showUP["uID"]; ?>);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {    
  $('a#fav').click(function() {
    return ($(this).hasClass('active'))
      ? removeFav('<?php echo $showUP["uID"]; ?>')
      : addFav('<?php echo $showUP["uID"]; ?>');
  });
});
```

Comment: Please have a quick look at the 'how to format code' question on meta.stackoverflow.com: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks